# Rails model concept with multiple sources

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have a document management system. I have a data set that can run through a program (another kind of file) which can be turned into images, a different kind of data, or even a new data set. I have to keep track of this "lineage".

If I was thinking in Mysql terms directly, I would add a "source" column and link each file to the file that it was created from.

I can't think of a logical way to do this within the confines of Ruby on Rails. Any ideas/hints/tips?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "within the confines of Ruby on Rails". You want to think in terms of your data first, structuring it in a way that makes sense logically and functionally. Then choose the tool for manipulation and rendering (Ruby on Rails). RoR can do just about whatever you want with it.

Comment: Are you looking for a tree data structure, to track parent/child relationships?  There are lots of ROR plugins to do this.  Can each document only have 1 parent, or can it have multiple?  as @mbratch says, rails can do many things, need to get the data model worked out.

Comment: Yes a tree data structure. Each document can have only one parent.

Comment: look at things like acts_as_tree or ancestry gem:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is GraphDBs. You can try neo4j www.neo4j.org/‎

Comment: Thanks I will look into it and make this the answer if I find it is what im looking for!

Comment: So after looking into this, this is a database while I was looking for how to relate my tree data structure in the Rails language. We have all our data in an Oracle database right now and I don't think that is ever going to change.

Comment: Ohk, then it is better to keep the old reference with new ones. You can make use of Rails self-associations.